# Spring Not Mapping Composite Key Entity To Database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities User and Focus for which I must store a ranking such that a User can have a ranking for many Focus', and a Focus may have many users. To handle this I've followed https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many part 3 whereby I have the 2 following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "UserBaseRatings")
public class Rating {

    @EmbeddedId
    RatingKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userID")
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("focusID")
    @JoinColumn(name="focusID")
    private Focus focus;

    private BigDecimal baseRating;

    protected Rating(){}

    public Rating(User user, Focus focus, BigDecimal baseRating) {
        this.user = user;
        this.focus = focus;
        this.baseRating = baseRating;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Focus getFocus() {
        return focus;
    }

    public void setFocus(Focus focus) {
        this.focus = focus;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBaseRating() {
        return baseRating;
    }

    public void setBaseRating(BigDecimal baseRating) {
        this.baseRating = baseRating;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class RatingKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="userID")
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name="focusID")
    private Long focusID;

    protected RatingKey(){}

    public RatingKey(Long userID, Long focusID) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    public Long getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(Long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public Long getFocusID() {
        return focusID;
    }

    public void setFocusID(Long focusID) {
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        RatingKey ratingKey = (RatingKey) o;
        return Objects.equals(userID, ratingKey.userID) &&
                Objects.equals(focusID, ratingKey.focusID);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userID, focusID);
    }
}
```

The table for UserBaseRatings has a default value of 1 for baseRating such that if a user does not have a rating on the current focus their rating should be 1. I'm running into a problem where if the user hasn't made a rating then the set of Rating's is empty instead of having a rating of 1 for each focus that exists.

User:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "userHashedPassword")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String email;

    //probably being reset
    @Transient
    private List<String> groups = new LinkedList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "UserRoles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "userID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "roleID"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    protected User(){}

    public User(String userHashedPassword, String userName, String email, Set<Role> roles){
        this.password = userHashedPassword;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setId(Long userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUsername(String name) {
        this.userName = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Set<Rating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
}
```

Focus:

```
@Entity
public class Focus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long focusID;

    private String focusCategory;

    private String focusName;

    private String focusExplanation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "focus")
    Set<Rating> ratings;

    //image

    protected Focus(){}

    public Focus(String focusCategory, String focusName, String focusExplanation, Set<Rating> ratings){
        this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
        this.focusName = focusName;
        this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public Long getFocusId() {
        return focusID;
    }

    public void setFocusId(Long focusID) {
        this.focusID = focusID;
    }

    public String getFocusCategory() {
        return focusCategory;
    }

    public void setFocusCategory(String focusCategory) {
        this.focusCategory = focusCategory;
    }

    public String getFocusName() {
        return focusName;
    }

    public void setFocusName(String focusName) {
        this.focusName = focusName;
    }

    public String getFocusExplanation() {
        return focusExplanation;
    }

    public void setFocusExplanation(String focusExplanation) {
        this.focusExplanation = focusExplanation;
    }

    public Set<Rating> getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Set<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
}
```

What am I missing that will allow a User's Ratings to be populated with the default value for each Focus that exists in the database?

Edit: Added @PrePersist and @PreUpdate to the Rating entity:

```
@Entity(name = "UserBaseRatings")
public class Rating {

    @EmbeddedId
    RatingKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userID")
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("focusID")
    @JoinColumn(name="focusID")
    private Focus focus;

    private BigDecimal baseRating;

    protected Rating(){}

    public Rating(User user, Focus focus, BigDecimal baseRating) {
        this.user = user;
        this.focus = focus;
        this.baseRating = baseRating;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Focus getFocus() {
        return focus;
    }

    public void setFocus(Focus focus) {
        this.focus = focus;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBaseRating() {
        return baseRating;
    }

    public void setBaseRating(BigDecimal baseRating) {
        this.baseRating = baseRating;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if(baseRating == null) {
            baseRating = BigDecimal.ONE;
        }
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        if(baseRating == null) {
            baseRating = BigDecimal.ONE;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=` from `none` to `update` also made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ORM all default values have to be explicitly declared. It can be done this way

```
@Entity(name = "UserBaseRatings")
public class Rating {

    // ...

    private BigDecimal baseRating = BigDecimal.ONE;

    // ...
}
```

or use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate`

```
@Entity(name = "UserBaseRatings")
public class Rating {
    
    // ...
    
    private BigDecimal baseRating;
        
    // ...
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if(baseRating == null) {
           baseRating = BigDecimal.ONE;
        }
    }  
    
    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        if(baseRating == null) {
           baseRating = BigDecimal.ONE;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I added the PrePersist and PreUpdate annotations however it's made no difference. Perhaps my understanding of Embedded classes are wrong - I thought that it would populate the ratings table, entity and therefore a User's Rating set on start up based on userID and focusID (pre-existing entities/tables). What would I need to do to make this the case?

Comment: Ah I'm not saving it and thats why it wouldn't be generating tables in the DB. In my case however, where should I be saving the entity? I need a Ranking entity generated for each pre-existing User and Focus, would I need to manually use the user and focus repository to find the table entries on startup then create and save the rankings from that? I thought this process would be automatically done by Spring

Comment: I misunderstood your issue. Do you want to make Spring generate table column with default value?

Comment: I want Spring to automatically generate a Rating for each existing User and Focus, for example if I have User: Bob and Focus: Maths, and Focus: Science, I would like Spring to create a Rating with Bob's userID + mathsID and a rating with Bobs userID + scienceID all with a default value of 1 which will then be saved to the database and hence reflected in my User entity. I thought embedded classes would do this automatically but i must be wrong

Comment: Spring does not generate empty fields of existing entities. It manages entities persisted from the application

Comment: My intention was to not generate an empty field, but to generate this Ranking entity from persisted User and Focus entities. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It can generate Ranking entity if you add sucn a behavior in `@PrePersist` only

Comment: I see, so in other words you can't generate and persist entities based on entities that already exist? It will only be generated when a new User entity is persisted